# Is there any way to install Empathy 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, empathy

I have just upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04 and I was disappointed to see that the Empathy version supplied with it (3.8.6) still suffers from the same problems that were introduced in Ubuntu 12.10, where the contacts are huge and cannot be sorted by status... consequently I have to scroll down through tens of 'Idle' people I never talk to, to find the contacts I want alphabetically (this used to work fine on the version supplied with 12.04).

Version 3.9.4 carries some fixes to the contact list sorting, so I was hoping that at least this version (which was released in July) would come with the new Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there any way to upgrade to the latest Empathy version safely?

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://pkgs.org/download/empathy

Under Debian Sid, download either of one

- [empathy 3.12 64-bit](http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-amd64/empathy_3.12.1-1_amd64.deb.html)
- [empathy 3.12 32-bit](http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-i386/empathy_3.12.1-1_i386.deb.html)

download and install using `sudo dpkg -i <path to .deb file>`

Comment: I tried to open it with the Ubuntu Software Centre before installing it with `dpkg` and it says `Breaks existing package 'account-plugin-aim' dependency empathy (= 3.8.6-0ubuntu9)`. Is it still safe to use `dpkg`?

Comment: No actually I think it will give an error in the dpkg installation but still you can try

Comment: Yep, I think it is the same error just reported differently by `dpkg`: `dpkg: error processing archive empathy_3.12.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/mission-control-plugins.0/mcp-account-manager-goa.so', which is also in package mcp-account-manager-goa 3.8.6-0ubuntu9`. Any way I can upgrade whatever is the dependency (without running into a manual dependency management hell)?